# Find record and group period when a status change at last

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table rows like this.

```
acc start_dat   end_dat n_type
aa  1/1/2017    2/2/2017    er
aa  2/2/2017    4/2/2017    er
aa  4/2/2017    1/3/2017    ok
aa  1/3/2017    12/3/2017   ok
aa  12/3/2017   15/4/2017   er
aa  15/4/2017   3/5/2017    er
aa  3/5/2017    5/5/2017    er
aa  5/5/2017      null      ok
bb  12/2/2017   4/3/2017    er
bb  4/3/2017    20/3/2017   er
bb  20/3/2017   13/4/2017   er
bb  13/4/2017   4/5/2017    ok
bb  4/5/2017    7/6/2017    er
bb  7/6/2017    3/7/2017    er
bb  3/7/2017     null       ok
```

I want to group the last status before change to ok with end_Dat = null  for calculate date at start to end

```
acc start_dat   end_dat duration_day
aa  12/3/2017   5/5/2017    52
bb  4/5/2017    3/7/2017    60
```

Are you have any idea to solve it?

Comment: Are there exactly two possible values for `n_type`, **er** and **ok**? If there are more than two possible values, and you only need the last status change (for example from **er** to **st** (assuming that is another possible `n_type`) before the most recent **ok**, then the answer you accepted will not find the start and end dates for the **st** status - it will find **er** and **st** treated as if they were the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your math seems incorrect, the day count from 12/3/2017 to 5/5/2017 is 54, not 52. Was that a typo?

You need to group consecutive rows with the same `n_type`. "Consecutive" is as ordered by `start_dat`, and the grouping is done separately for each `acc`. This is a direct application of the Tabibitosan method for creating group identifiers in such "gaps and islands" problems. The "Tabibitosan method" is the use of the difference of two `row_number()` functions, using different `partition by` clauses, in the innermost subquery in the solution below.

Other than that the query is standard. Group by `acc, n_type, grp` (where `grp` is the new grouping flag created in the innermost subquery), compute the minimum start date and the maximum end date for each group, and select the group with the highest `grp` flag after ignoring all the groups where `n_type = 'ok'`.

```
select acc, start_dat, end_dat, end_dat - start_dat as duration_day
from   (
         select   acc, min(start_dat) as start_dat, max(end_dat) as end_dat,
                  row_number() over (partition by acc order by grp desc) as rn
         from     (
                    select acc, start_dat, end_dat, n_type,
                         row_number() over (partition by acc         order by start_dat) - 
                         row_number() over (partition by acc, n_type order by start_dat)
                         as grp
                    from   inputs
                  )
         where    n_type != 'ok'
         group by acc, n_type, grp
       )
where  rn = 1
;
```

Comment: http://rextester.com/JNF33335  this logic is awesome!! I spend more time  to understand.  Thanks so much.

Comment: To understand how this works, run the innermost subquery by itself (remove everything before and after it). Google for "Tabibitosan method" to find numerous discussions and examples. After you understand that part, run only the middle subquery (with the sub-subquery) and see what that does. Then you can run the full query. See what each step accomplishes and how it is used in the next step.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of "ok" records after each record and then use that for aggregation:

```
select acc, min(start_dat), max(end_dat),
       (max(end_dat) - min(start_dat)) as diff
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when n_type = 'ok' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by acc order by start_dat desc) as numoks_after
      from t
     ) t
where numoks_after = 1 and n_type <> 'ok'
group by acc;
```

Comment: http://rextester.com/DGJIWX21590  I never use the sum(case). This logic is amazing . Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can accept whichever answer you like.  But is there a reason why you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: in case http://rextester.com/CXB24635  it's cannot solve this problem because if in last +1 record is same priority . sum in numoks_after is no correct.  but  thank for respond and this logic is good for this  case.